# Adding Password protection to Iron-Speed Application

Tags: sql, sql-server, ironspeed

I have an Iron-Speed application generated from my database and wish to add password protection to all of the pages.

I already have a table in my database with usernames and passwords, how do I apply this to my Iron-Speed pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I found that Iron-Speed (What a program!) already has a wizard built in for security purposes, such as password protection.

By going to Tools --> Role-Based Security Wizard, everything can bet set up by linking it to the relevant fields in the 'User' table in your database.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you just required to have 3 tables in your Database :

- Users
- Roles
- UserRoles  (Relation between both)

It also create login automatically

and you can also get Users Info by Get methods of :

```
BaseClasses.Utils.SecurityControls.Get___
```

from any page